# Recalc entropy and free energy from scaled hessian

Tags: orca

I have already performed a FREQ calculation on my system. Following the manual, I then changed the scalar factor accordingly to the theory level I've done my calculation.

As procedure suggested in the manual, I then ran `orca_vib myjob_scaled_freq.hess`.

How can I obtain the Free Gibbs Energy from this new hessian file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is from the online Orca [tutorials](https://www.orcasoftware.de/tutorials_orca/prop/thermo.html#changing-the-temperature-after-the-calculation):

```
! PrintThermoChem
%geom
  inhessname "basename.hess"
end
%freq temp 298 end

*xyzfile 0 1 geometry.xyz
```

This reads the Hessian and prints the theormochemical analysis at the temperature specified.